# Can masses move in 2+1 gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, differential-geometry, geometry

I would like to understand basic concepts of the general relativity in 2+1 spacetime. As far as I know, GR predicts that such a spacetime is flat everywhere except for the point masses which create angular deficit proportional to their mass. Flatland with one point mass is like surface of cone. I imagine that when one adds other point masses the Flatland can be folded to a (convex) polyhedron (then there is the constraint on total masses, since total angular deficit is 720 degrees) (see note #1). I assume that a 2d Flatlander would not (at least locally) notice crossing the edges when moving from one face of polyhedron to another.

The problem I have with this model is that when one heavy body which defines the Flatland is set to motion, its mass must change and - more surprisingly from a local point of view - also masses of the neighboring bodies to keep the total of 720 degrees. The image shows cube with a vertex moving along edge to its middle with corresponding angular deficits.

On the other hand, I know that 2+1 gravity and motion of point masses have been considered seriously by Gott (in his two strings time machine), Caroll, Guth, t' Hooft and others. Where is error in my naive model?

**Edited**: Given the first answer and comments I should maybe be more precise:

*Is a motion which requires change of angular deficit (and hence mass) of the surrounding point masses possible, or is possible only motion when all angular deficits are kept constant? Anyway, for a Flatender living on the polyhedron surface the situation looks like there is an interaction between the point masses, despite the fact the spacetime is flate in between them. Or is such a configuration (initial condition) simply impossible?*

**Edited**: I have overlooked the fact that a point mass cannot be just "set to motion" by a miracle - *total momentum must be conserved*. I will think it over and prepare a better example.

**Edited**: This papers by 't Hooft may contain answer:

[The evolution of gravitating point particles in 2+1 dimensions](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/evolution_2plus1_dim.pdf) (pdf)

[Three-dimensional Einstein gravity: dynamics of flat space](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/Deser_Jack_tH_ThreeD_Grav_1984.pdf) (pdf)

[image]

**Notes** (added in later edits):

1) Gott & Alpert: *General Relativity in a (2+1)-Dimensional Space-Time* (Gen. Relat. Gravit. 16:243-247, 1984):

"Consider a convex polyhedron with a finite number of faces. The faces and
edges have no intrinsic curvature and represent solutions to the vacuum field
equations. The vertices each have an angle deficit (like the vertex of a cone) and
represent point masses. For example, a universe shaped like the surface of a cube
represents a vacuum with 8 point masses of $M = \pi/2$ each (three squares meet at
each vertex giving each an angle deficit of $\pi/2$). The Einstein static universe of
equation (6) may be approximated by a polyhedron of many faces containing
many vertices each with small angle deficits. The total mass in such a closed
universe is always $M_u = 4\pi$."

In my opinion, there are also some *nonconvex* polyhedra which work well.

Comment: Polyhedron is kind of a special case (because it implies finite volume). Why not consider first two point particles with small angular deficit. This could be mapped onto 2d plane (times time) with two slices cut out (and glued along the line of cut)

Comment: @user23660 Because in such a case there is only *upper* limit of the total angular deficit and hence mass (in open Flatland): 360 degrees (otherwise you cannot unfold the Flatland without overlaping). Then I understand that the two particles can move freely.

Comment: So what you are asking is, if compactness of multiconic space-time (i.e. polyhedron) would imply additional constraints?

Comment: @user23660 I guess I do :-)

Comment: For minimal case of 4 particles (tetrahedron) the angular deficits of vertices define the tetrahedron up to rescaling. The only allowable motion is enlargement (or contraction) of the tetrahedron (cosmological expansion of sorts).

Comment: But adding the fifth particle also adds two additional degrees of freedom: there are deformations other than rescaling (preserving deficits). Your example of the cube has even more degrees of movement (scaling along one axis for example). So we can hypothesize that more particles (and less deficit for each)  means more degrees of motion, so in the limit of infinitely many particles the number of degrees of freedom per particle would be as for the non-gravitating case (2 degrees per particle).

Comment: Oops! Upon reflection, I realized that tetrahedron does have 3-parametric deformation which preserve the angle deficit of vertices (one parameter corresponds to similarity transform). Then, the addition of each next vertex does add two more degrees of freedom.

Comment: @user23660 In a sense, minimal polyhedron have 3 vertices - imagine tetrahedron flatened to zero volume - the fourth vertex have angular deficit 0, in other words you can remove it.

Comment: Yes, and for this system of 3 particles the only allowable evolution is cosmological expansion with linear dependence of scale factor on time ($a(t)= C (t-t_0)$).

Comment: @user23660 Why is only the linear evolution possible?

Comment: Because there are no forces to alter the speed. That aspect is fully equivalent to open case.

Answer (score 1):

Differential geometry predicts that the *Weyl tensor* vanishes in 2+1 dimensions. General relativity predicts that the Ricci curvature vanishes in a vacuum -- i.e. no forces at a distance. So acceleration due to gravity can still exist in 3 dimensional spacetime, but only in a region with a non-zero stress-energy tensor.

Comment: It looks like the OP's question is phrased in terms of Regge-style discrete spacetime, so in this context his statement that the spacetime is flat everywhere except at vertices carrying mass points would be right?

Comment: @twistor59: Surely, yes, since the SEM Tensor is non - vanishing at those points.

Comment: I don't quite understand the answer, I'm afraid, but it seems to me that your reasoning is not restricted to the closed Flatland (where total sum of angular deficits equals 720 degrees). Does it mean that Gott time machine using two cosmic strings is impossible simply because the string (which are analog to the point mass or vertices here) can't move relative to each other?

Comment: I don't see the reasoning behind the phrase *"So to answer your question, the masses would not be able to move unless they're somewhere like inside the Earth"*. Why in order to move mass have to be in some curved space-time? Point particle can move in flat space-time independent of presence of gravity at all and peculiar type of such gravity should not exclude such motion (just change the interactions between such particles).

Comment: @user23660: Oh, yes, you're right. I meant that they can't accelerate due to gravity, I've fixed it.

Comment: @LeosOndra: Right. It applies to all 2+1 dimensional spacetimes.

Comment: Well, in case of normal GR, $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ at point P does not imply flat geomtry at that point. And actually objects do get well accelerated in regions, where $R_{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick: But in 2+1 $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ implies $R_{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}=0$. So the geometry *is* flat.

Comment: I should perhaps clarify that I am not interested in accelerated motion due to presence of the other point masses but in possibility of _any_ motion.

Comment: @LeosOndra: Such motion **is possible** even for convex polyhedron as long as there are enough vertices, just the number of degrees freedom will be smaller then in open (noncompact) space.

Comment: @LeosOndra: I don't see the problem with general motion.  You have motion in special relativity just fine.  If you're worried about discontinuity, you don't necessarily need sharp edges to your matter distribution, you can have the function and an arbitrary number of deriviatives go nicely to zero at the edge of your matter distribution.